# chances of choosing 1 woman in a group consisting of 3 women and 13 men

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

My discrete math class consists of 16 people total: 3 woman and 13 men.  If my professor handed out 16 envelopes, with one having a golden ticket in it, what are the chances that a woman gets the golden ticket?

I was trying to do something with C(16,1)*3 ... but for some reason that doesn't seem right.  It might be, and I might be second guessing myself.  As a woman, I want to know what the chances are of one of us girls winning.

Comment: Remember, "or" means add. So it could be one girl OR another girl OR another girl that gets the ticket.

Comment: There are $16$ **equally likely** outcomes (person A gets the prize, person B does, and so on). Of these $16$ outcomes, $3$ are considered **favourable**. The required probability is therefore $\frac{3}{16}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: The chances wouldn’t change if there were just the envelope with the golden ticket, and your professor picked the recipient at random: each student is equally likely to get it in either version of the experiment.

Comment: So if there's a 1 in 16 chance for me to get it, and a 1 in 16 chance for Caryn to get it and a 1 in 16 chance for Vikki to get it, would it be a 1 in 16^3 for a woman to get it?

Comment: Or would it be 1 in 16+16+16?  I always get confused on this.

Comment: @Chryssy: Stop and think about what you just wrote: $1$ in $16^3$ is a much **smaller** chance than $1$ in $16$. If there’s already a $1$ in $16$ chance that you get it, then surely the chance that a woman gets it must be at least that big, right? And $1$ in $48$ has the same problem: it’s smaller than $1$ in $16$.

Comment: Okay, that's making sense.  So there's a 3 in 16 chance for a woman to get it.

Comment: @Chryssy: There you go! Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to combine that with another scenario.  I know that if he hands out 3 silver tickets, there are 455 possible groups of 3 silver-ticket holders C(15,3) and there will be 1 person left over, holding the golden ticket.  The chances of the 3 women holding silver tickets is 1 in 455, if you don't account for the 1 golden ticket.

Comment: So if I want to know what the chances of us 3 women holding the silver tickets is including the possibility of one of us holding the golden ticket, what do I add to the 455?

Comment: @Chryssy: There are $\binom{16}3$ possible groups of holders of the $3$ silver tickets, so the chance that they go to the $3$ women is just $1/560$. Are you also interested in the probability that all three of the women get one of the four special tickets, irrespective of whether one of them gets the gold?

Comment: No, I want to know just the chances of us holding the silver tickets.

Comment: @Chryssy: That’s $1$ in $\binom{16}3$, or $1$ in $560$: it’s as if the professor were just handing out the $3$ silver tickets to $3$ randomly chosen members of the class. There are $\binom{16}3$ possible sets of $3$ recipients, and the women are only one of those sets.

Comment: I think I may be making this more complicated than it has to be... C(16,3) makes sense...